# want to compile userfaultfd ecample

Tags: linux-kernel, page-fault

I want to handle user space page handler.
Following url shows usage of userfaultfd
https://www.cons.org/cracauer/cracauer-userfaultfd.html
However I cannot compile this program.
Error is as follow.

```
userfaultfd.c: In function ‘handler’:
userfaultfd.c:141:34: error: storage size of ‘wp’ isn’t known
       struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
                                  ^
userfaultfd.c:147:21: error: ‘UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (ioctl(fd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1) {
                     ^
userfaultfd.c:147:21: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
userfaultfd.c: In function ‘main’:
userfaultfd.c:343:30: error: storage size of ‘wp’ isn’t known
   struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
                              ^
userfaultfd.c:346:13: error: ‘UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT_MODE_WP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   wp.mode = UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT_MODE_WP;
             ^
userfaultfd.c:347:19: error: ‘UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1) {
```

Why cannot i compile this program?
my environment:
Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

```
/*
 * Example program about using userfaultfd(2) for garbage collection.
 *
 * This establishes a couple pages, all of which are filled from
 * compressed files on disk when first accessed.  For simplicity these are 
 * one file per page.  Files are written at the beginning of the program.
 *
 * Later, this program demonstrates the use of write protection to get 
 * a notification on write access, analogous to using mprotect(!PROT_WRITE)
 * and doing the bookkeeping in a SIGSEGV handler.
 *
 */

#include <linux/userfaultfd.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

#include <poll.h>
#include <pthread.h>

const int pagesize = 4096;

// Bookkeeping about pages.  Part of the GC, not of userfaultfd handling
struct page_attr {
  int has_been_brought_in_p;
  int has_been_written_when_wp_p;  
};

// Random parameters we pass to threads instead of using globals
struct pass2uffd_thread {
  int fd;
  long long *begin;
  size_t size;
  size_t n_pages;
  struct page_attr *pages;
};

void floatsleep(float seconds)
{
  struct timespec req;

  req.tv_sec = floor(seconds);
  req.tv_nsec = (float)(seconds - req.tv_sec) * 1000000000.0;
  nanosleep(&req, NULL);
}

// This is doing the work in the uffd handler thread
void *handler(void *data)
{
  struct pass2uffd_thread *params = data;
  int fd = params->fd;

  printf("thread: fd is %d\n",fd);

  for (;;) {
    struct uffd_msg msg;

    struct pollfd pollfd[1];
    pollfd[0].fd = params->fd;
    pollfd[0].events = POLLIN;
    int pollres;

    pollres = poll(pollfd, 1, -1);
    switch (pollres) {
    case -1:
      perror("poll userfaultfd");
      continue;
      break;
    case 0: continue; break;
    case 1: break;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "got %d fds out of poll\n", pollres);
      exit(2);
    }
    if (pollfd[0].revents & POLLERR) {
      fprintf(stderr, "POLLERR on userfaultfd\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (!(pollfd[0].revents & POLLIN)) {
      continue;
    }

    int readret;
    readret = read(fd, &msg, sizeof(msg));
    if (readret == -1) {
      if (errno == EAGAIN)
    continue;
      perror("read userfaultfd");
    }
    if (readret != sizeof(msg)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "short read, not expected, exiting\n");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (msg.event & UFFD_EVENT_PAGEFAULT)
      printf("==> Event is pagefault on %p flags 0x%llx write? 0x%llx wp? 0x%llx\n"
         , (void *)msg.arg.pagefault.address
         , msg.arg.pagefault.flags
         , msg.arg.pagefault.flags & UFFD_PAGEFAULT_FLAG_WRITE
         , msg.arg.pagefault.flags & UFFD_PAGEFAULT_FLAG_WP
         );

    long long addr = msg.arg.pagefault.address;
    long long page_begin = addr - (addr % pagesize);
    long long whichpage = (page_begin - (long long)params->begin) / 
      pagesize;
    if (whichpage > params->n_pages) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Page %lld too high\n", whichpage);
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("Messing with page %lld\n", whichpage);

    /*
     * Proper sequence is important here.
     *
     * For the GC we expect that write-protected pages can only
     * be pages already backed by physical pages.
     * Regular writes into unprotected pages that come before
     * reads need the page be filled.
     *
     * So we do the WP case first and get it out of the way.
     * Then both of the other cases need the page read.
     */

    if (msg.arg.pagefault.flags & UFFD_PAGEFAULT_FLAG_WP) {
      //  send write unlock
      struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
      wp.range.start = (long long)params->begin;
      wp.range.len = (long long)params->size;
      wp.mode = 0;
      printf("sending !UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT event to userfaultfd\n");
      fflush(stdout);
      if (ioctl(fd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1) {
    perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT)");
      }
      params->pages[whichpage].has_been_written_when_wp_p = 1;
      continue;
    }
    // Page has never been filled, so do that now.
    // Note that this relies on user only write-protecting pages
    // after they have been filled.  That won't be the case
    // in a real GC.

    FILE *f;
    char cmdname[8192];
    snprintf(cmdname, sizeof(cmdname), "zcat tmp%lld.gz", whichpage);
    f = popen(cmdname, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
      perror("popen zcat");
      exit(1);
    }
    char buf[pagesize];
    if (fread(buf, pagesize, 1, f) == 0) {
      perror("fread");
      exit(1);
    }
    if (fclose(f)) {
      perror("fclose");
      exit(1);
    }

    struct uffdio_copy cp;
    cp.src = (long long)buf;
    cp.dst = (long long)addr;
    cp.len = (long long)pagesize;
    cp.mode = 0; // fixme - is there a symbol for this?
    printf("sending UFFDIO_COPY event to userfaultfd\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (ioctl(fd, UFFDIO_COPY, &cp) == -1) {
      perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_COPY)");
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}

// this function can be thread main body or directly run
void *do_some_work(void *data)
{
  struct pass2uffd_thread *params = data;

  long long *region = params->begin;

  floatsleep(0.2);
  printf("worker writing into write-protected area at %p\n", region);
  fflush(stdout);
  *region = 43;
  printf("I survived that\n"); fflush(stdout);
  floatsleep(0.2);

  return NULL;
}

void write_testfiles()
{
  long long word = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEF;
  FILE *f;
  char *cmds[] = {
    "gzip > tmp0.gz",
    "gzip > tmp1.gz",
    "gzip > tmp2.gz",
    "gzip > tmp3.gz",
    NULL
  };
  char **cmd;

  for (cmd = cmds; *cmd; cmd++) {
    f = popen(*cmd, "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
      perror("popen gzip");
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < pagesize / sizeof(word); i++) {
      if (!fwrite(&word, sizeof(word), 1, f)) {
    perror("fwrite");
    exit(1);
      }
    }
    if (fclose(f)) {
      perror("fclose");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  long long *region;
  const int n_pages = 128;
  pthread_t uffd_thread;
  int uffd;

  write_testfiles();

  printf("userfaultf syscall #: %d\n", __NR_userfaultfd);

  uffd = syscall(__NR_userfaultfd, O_CLOEXEC | O_NONBLOCK);
  if (uffd == -1) {
    perror("syscall");
    exit(2);
  }

  int uffd_flags;
  uffd_flags = fcntl(uffd, F_GETFD, NULL);
  printf("userfaultfd flags: 0x%llX, fd is %d\n", (long long)uffd_flags, uffd);

  struct uffdio_api uffdio_api;
  uffdio_api.api = UFFD_API;
  uffdio_api.features = 0;
  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_API, &uffdio_api)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "UFFDIO_API\n");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("Features: 0x%llx\n", uffdio_api.features);
  if (uffdio_api.api != UFFD_API) {
    fprintf(stderr, "UFFDIO_API error %Lu\n", uffdio_api.api);
    return 1;
  }

#if 0
  printf("userfaultfd api: 0x%llX -> 0x%llX\n", UFFD_API, uffdio_api.api);
  printf("userfaultfd ioctls: 0x%llX (0x%llx)\n", uffdio_api.ioctls, 
     (long long)UFFDIO_REGISTER);
#endif

  region = (long long *)
    mmap(NULL, pagesize * n_pages, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE
     , MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
  if (!region) {
    perror("mmap");
    exit(2);
  }
  if (posix_memalign((void **)®ion, pagesize, pagesize * n_pages)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot align by pagesize %d\n", pagesize);
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("mapped at %p - %p\n", region, region + pagesize * n_pages);

  struct uffdio_register uffdio_register;
  uffdio_register.range.start = (unsigned long)region;
  uffdio_register.range.len = pagesize * n_pages;

  uffdio_register.mode = UFFDIO_REGISTER_MODE_MISSING | 
    UFFDIO_REGISTER_MODE_WP;

  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_REGISTER, &uffdio_register) == -1) {
    perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_REGISTER)");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("userfaultfd ioctls: 0x%llx\n", uffdio_register.ioctls);

  int expected = UFFD_API_RANGE_IOCTLS;
  if ((uffdio_register.ioctls & expected) != expected) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl set is incorrect\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Our bookkeeping.  Part of the GC, has nothing to do with
  // userfaultfd.  Updated in the uffd thread.
  struct page_attr *pages;
  pages = malloc(n_pages * sizeof(struct page_attr));
  if (pages == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
  }
  bzero(pages, n_pages * sizeof(struct page_attr));

  /* 
   * Set up and start uffd thread.
   */
  struct pass2uffd_thread thr_params;
  thr_params.fd = uffd;
  thr_params.begin = region;
  thr_params.size = pagesize * n_pages;
  thr_params.n_pages = n_pages;
  thr_params.pages = pages;
  pthread_create(&uffd_thread, NULL, handler, &thr_params);

  printf("mainline testing read on page 0\n"); fflush(stdout);
  printf("region first word currently is: 0x%llx\n", *region);

  printf("mainline testing read on page 2\n"); fflush(stdout);
  printf("region first word currently is: 0x%llx\n"
     , *(region + 2 * pagesize / sizeof(*region)));

  printf("mainline writing writable page 1\n"); fflush(stdout);
  *(region + pagesize / sizeof(*region)) = 0x42;

  // test write protect on first page
  struct uffdio_writeprotect wp;
  wp.range.start = (unsigned long)region;
  wp.range.len = pagesize * n_pages;
  wp.mode = UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT_MODE_WP;
  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT, &wp) == -1) {
    perror("ioctl(UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT)");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("worker writing into write-protected page 0\n"); fflush(stdout);
  *region = 0x43;
  printf("I survived that\n"); fflush(stdout);

  if (ioctl(uffd, UFFDIO_UNREGISTER, &uffdio_register.range)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl unregister failure\n");
    return 1;
  }

  printf("pages first words currently are:\n"
     "0x%llx/0x%llx 0x%llx/0x%llx 0x%llx/0x%llx \n"
     , *region
     , *(region + 1)
     , *(region + pagesize / sizeof(*region))
     , *(region + 1 + pagesize / sizeof(*region))
     , *(region + 2 * pagesize / sizeof(*region))
     , *(region + 1 + 2* pagesize / sizeof(*region))
     );

  free(pages);
  // fixme - various other cleanup
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mainline Linux kernel there is no support for `UFFDIO_WRITEPROTECT` system call (thus, `struct uffdio_writeprotect` isn't defined too).

Probably, the example you are trying to compile is based on Linux kernel from Andrea Arcangeli's [repo](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/andrea/aa.git/), its [include/uapi/linux/linux/userfaultfd.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/andrea/aa.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/userfaultfd.h) header contains needed definitions.

For use that feature, you need to build appropriate kernel, install headers (with `make headers_install`) and build *libc* library based on these headers.

Comment: Yes. Also it looks like the change is yet to be merged to mainline kernel. Please check http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-mm/msg97416.html

Comment: If I understand things correctly, the mail you refer to corresponds to `linux-mm` *developer* branch, which is not a *mainline* kernel.